# ¿Cómo enviar email con php cada cierto determinado tiempo?

Tags: php

Tengo un bucle for que envía una cierta cantidad de correros, pero me gustaría saber como hacer para que ese bucle for envíe los correos en una escala determinada de tiempo:

```
<?php

$a = 1;

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  $destinatario = "magodiesan@gmail.com";
  $asunto = "Hola Diesan";
  $cuerpo = "Como estas?";
  mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo);
  echo "<h1>Correos enviados</h1>";
}

?>
```

Se me ocurre hacerlo con el setInvertal() de javascript, pero no sé como integrarlo. No se mucho php, y este script lo necesito para algo sencillo de una sola vez.

Comment: Para estos casos las colas de tareas suelen funcionar bien. Son algo más complejas de integrar, pero ofrecen muchas posibilidades, entre ellas lo que estás buscando. En GitHub seguro que hay algo que se adapte a lo que necesitas.

Comment: De esta forma solo llegan algunos correos no llegan todos, ejemplo de 10 llegan 4 o 6 pero en su mayoria de las veces o casi siempre no llegan a todos los destinatarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres hacerlo en PHP desde el lado del servidor, simplemente puedes utilizar la función [Sleep](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sleep.php).

```
<?php

$a = 1;

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
  $destinatario = "magodiesan@gmail.com";
  $asunto = "Hola Diesan";
  $cuerpo = "Como estas?";
  mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo);
  echo "<h1>Correos enviados</h1>";
  // Duerme el programa 5 segundos, luego continúa
  sleep(5);
}

?>
```

Si quieres que la llamada se realice desde js/jquery en el lado del cliente, como bien dices deberías usar setInterval y una llamada [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), en caso de que quieras mantener la ejecución asíncrona.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió de mucho.

Comment: Pero lo malo de esto es que el programa se queda cargando tal como sospechaba, probaré con javascript a ver qué sucede.

Comment: En principio el  programa acaba con el bucle, pero ciertamente se queda "dormido" en su totalidad. Si tiene otras partes que ejecutar, hasta que no acabe con la tarea pendiente, no responde o continúa.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando setInterval() y JQuery. El proceso es llamar a tu función php desde js a través de JQuery con [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). El servidor ejecutará la función con el for enviando los correos.

Por ejemplo:

JS:

```
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $.get('server.php', function(response){
            alert("Respuesta: " + response);
        }); 
    }, 3000);
```

PHP (server.php):

```
$i = 1;

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
 //$destinatario = "magodiesan@gmail.com";
 //$asunto = "Hola Diesan";
 //$cuerpo = "Como estas?";
 //mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo);
 echo $i."correos enviados...";
}
```

Si probás este ejemplo, cada 3000 miliseg. se ejecuta el for en el servidor y obtienes como respuesta:

```
Respuesta:  1correos enviados...2correos enviados...3correos 
enviados...4correos enviados...5correos enviados...6correos 
enviados...7correos enviados...8correos enviados...9correos 
enviados...10correos enviados...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.